# Problems with SSH ProxyCommand execution

Tags: ssh

I'm following [this resource](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/) to set up something like a proxy server for ssh

My setup is exactly like the mention in the post:

```
Remote Server A
Machine-1
Machine-2
```

Machine-1 is the bastion server from which I can ssh to the remote server (using identity file)

Machine-2 can connect to Machine-1 using a password.

Requirement:

Connect to Remote Server(A) from Machine-2 via Machine-1

```
Machine-2 <--> Machine-1 <--> Remote Server(A)
```

Here how my command looks (running this command from machine-2)

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand=ssh -W user2@%h:%p user1@machine-1" user2@remote_server
```

But I yet to see the success.

The error I see on the

```
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I don't this often so I'm not sure what is wrong. But according to the resource the step done looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `user2@` part in your `ProxyCommand`. This should work:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand=ssh -W %h:%p user1@machine-1" user2@remote_server
```

However, it might be easier to write a config for this. Also, if you use `ProxyJump` instead of `ProxyCommand`, the config will be easier to read. Write these lines to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host machine-1
User user1

Host remote_server
User user2
ProxyJump machine-1
```

and after that, you can simply issue `ssh remote_server` command to log in to the `remote_server`, using `machine-1` as a stepping stone.

Comment: would it work if the remoteserver is accessible from machine1 using `key identification` whereas machine 2 can access machine1 using password does it has to be same authentication on each side?

Comment: also I will definitely try it but as I remember when I was using not using `user2` it failed but I will try it again.

Comment: also on ssh jump well may be later but right now my approach is to get the proxycommand thing going as I would be using that in `sftp -o sshoptions`

Comment: It will work no matter what usres you have on which machine, and what authentication methods are set up. The command will log in to `machine-1`, and from there to `remote_server`, using the authentication methods it would use, had you given the `ssh` command one by one from a terminal. Regarding your `sftp` comment: I think you are making it more difficult that it should be. With the config entries in the answer, you can simply issue `sftp remote_server`, and it will follow the same route as a normal SSH connection would.

Comment: I just tried the `ssh -o "ProxyCommand=ssh -W %h:%p user1@machine-1" user2@remote_server` and it failed since Not sure why I'm not able to get it working.

Same error `kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host `

Comment: I'm still not able to get it work.